# Map a syntax table to Unicode’s general categories

Tags: unicode, syntax-table, mapping

How would you go about mapping the [syntax table](https://www.gnu.org/software/emacs/manual/html_node/elisp/Syntax-Tables.html) of a major mode to Unicode’s [general categories](https://www.unicode.org/reports/tr44/tr44-26.html#General_Category_Values)?  For example, set whitespace class `-` for each character of the syntax table that belongs to Unicode category `Zs`, word syntax `w` for each `Lu`, and punctuation `.` for each `Po`.

My aim is to make functions like `skip-syntax-forward` and regexp constructs like `\s-` and `[:blank:]` operate in Unicode terms.

I know that `get-char-code-property` gets me the Unicode category, and `modify-syntax-entry` changes the syntax class for a single character.  But how do I apply these wholesale to every possible character?

Comment: Do you have a specific question, or do you just want someone to write the code for you? What have you written so far?